# Determine order of pole under condition: $ N|z-a|^{-\frac{5}{2}}| \leq |f(z)| \leq M|z-a|^{-\frac{7}{2}}. $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D \Rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, where $D$ is some domain. Let $a$ be a singularity of $f$.

Assume that there are an $r > 0$ and positive numbers $M$ and $N$ such that 
$$
N|z-a|^{-\frac{5}{2}}| \leq |f(z)| \leq M|z-a|^{-\frac{7}{2}},
$$
when $0 <|z-a|< r$.

Now $a$ is a pole of $f$ since $\lim_{z\to a} f(z) = \infty$. 
The order of the pole is higher than 2, since $\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)^2f(z) = \infty$. It is smaller than or equal to 4, since $\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)^4f(z) = 0$.

But my question is how would I determine whether the order of the pole is really 4, or in fact 3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)^4f(z) = 0$  implies that the order of the pole is *less than* $4$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your response! Could you elaborate on why that is? In my understanding $\lim{z \to a} (z-a)^4 f(z) = 0$ suggests that a is a removable singularity of $(z-a)^4 f(z)$. But not necessarily of $(z-a)^3 f(z)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has a pole of order $d$ at $z=a$ then $
 \lim_{z \to a} (z-a)^d f(z)$ exists and is $ \ne 0, \infty $.

It follows from your estimates that $\frac 52 \le d \le \frac 72$, and that leaves only one possible choice for the integer $d$.